# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Security Patches End Date

Tags: 14.04, updates, security

What is the end of life for security patches-updates for ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS?

I have seen that [EOL for standard support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) is 2022. Does this apply to security updates too?

Details of OS:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is already EOL - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Also 14.04.5 migrated to 14.04.6 back on March 8, 2019 - so you're system hasn't been upgraded in awhile - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/08/ubuntu-14-04-6-lts-released/

Comment: You have slightly misquoted the link, EoL for *standard support* of Ubuntu 14.04.6 is April 2019, *not* 2022. EoL for Ubuntu 14.04.6 ESM (Extended Security Maintenance) is April 2022. Note that ESM is a paid service (for [Ubuntu Advantage customers](https://ubuntu.com/esm)).

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_(Trusty_Tahr)) entry for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) says -

> Normal LTS support is set to continue until 25 April 2019,[218] after which extended security maintenance will be available to Ubuntu Advantage customers and as a separate commercial purchase, as was the case previously with 12.04.[219]

Consider upgrading to latest/ later LTS version for latest security support.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is already EOL, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM has already started it's life.

> This is a follow-up to the Extended Support warning sent a month ago
> to confirm that as of April 25, 2019, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS basic support
> has ended. No more package updates[1] will be accepted to the 14.04
> primary archive, and any subsequent support will be done via Extended
> Security Maintenance. Over the coming weeks, various images will be
> archived, and the primary archive will be copied to old-releases.
>
> Again, we remind you that for customers who can’t upgrade to 16.04 or
> later immediately, Canonical offers Extended Security Support for
> 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu Advantage customers, more info about which can be found here:
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 will transition to Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) on
> Thursday, April 25th, 2019.

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Also Ubuntu 14.04.6 was released on 8-March-2019, so your 14.04.5 hasn't been upgraded in awhile so I'd suggest taking note more carefully of your system(s); this upgrade didn't require re-install, just a `apt full-upgrade`

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/08/ubuntu-14-04-6-lts-released/

Please note LTS support ended for 14.04 LTS on the date in "**End of Standard Support"** column, the "**End of Life**" section includes the ESM (extended security maintenance) which is covered later in the page.  It is this bit of information that has probably confused you. ESM support requires payment, and signing up for Ubuntu Advantage with Canonical.

Comment: Of note:  I coped some flak over the wording (esp. heading) used in the 14.04 EOL notice on the fridge, as it was not the wording wanted by Canonical.  The (ESM available) I added later in the heading because they wanted to use language where it wasn't EOL but just end of standard support.  This wording '*disagreement*' may be repeated when 16.04 LTS reaches EOL/end-of-standard-support in the future